# Simple notation question about brackets

Tags: notation

Is this notation correct? I am not sure about the brackets.

$x^2=4$

$x=\{-2,2\}$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $x\in\{-2,2\}$ is more appropriate, since you're saying that $x$ is one of those two numbers rather than saying that $x$ itself is the set.

Comment: I suggest $x=\pm 2$, or $x=2,-2$. I don't think there is anything wrong with the brackets but it is not common

Comment: When you write $\{x\>|\>x^2=4\}$ it is not obvious what the intended "universe" is. E.g., $\{x\in{\mathbb N}\>|\>x^2=4\}=\{2\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to denote is $$x \in \{-2, 2\}$$

That is, you want to convey that $x$ is an element of the *solution set* $\{-2, 2\}$. $x$ is **not** equal to the set.

So simply replace the symbol "$=$" with the symbol "$\in$", and all is then good.